# Close Popup Method not Working for all Tests

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Close Popup Method not Working of all Tests
1. For example 20 out of 26 tests will pass.
2. on the six test which have failed the following code will not close the popuo box

```
    public void closeAlertPopupBox() {
    try {
        Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        alert.accept();
        System.out.println("The popup has been successfully closed");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to close the popup");
        Assert.assertFalse(true, "Unable to close the popup, Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally{
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, when the 6 tests fail, do they all fail at the same point? Are you catching an exception, or does it just not close? If there is an exception, what is it? Do all of these popups have something on them where `accept()` will do something?

Comment: @mrfreester thanks for the reply, the popup is the same and contains the button / text ok, all tests fail at the same point and the message im receiving is: org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Click OK to confirm your personal message is correct as this is exactly how it will be printed.}

Comment: Sounds like a fun one :). I'm guessing that exception happens after this `closeAlertPopupBox` method, do you know if you're catching an exception in your catch block? You have an explicit wait for the alert to be there, but my first guess is this is still a timing issue. Does this still fail when you step through the code with the debugger, or if you sleep for a few seconds before `alert.accept()`? If not then you might need to figure out something else to wait for.

Comment: @mrfreester it looks like if i set a fixed Thread.sleep() before the method it works, just weird how the .wait() dosnt work within the listed method :/

Comment: Yeah that's frustrating, maybe the accept button takes a minute to be clickable after the alert is present... It's a bit harder to wait for things on the alert itself.